# Two h:forms inside one h:form

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have two primefaces dialog that are inside in one h:form and i want to submit some required values from one dialog without submit required values from the other one:

```
 <h:form>
    <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="A">
      <h:inputText value="#{bean.value}" required="true" />
      <p:commandButton value="A" action="#{bean.someAction}" />
    </p:dialog>

    <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="B" >
      <h:inputText value="#{bean.otherValue}" required="true" />
      <p:commandButton value="B" action="#{bean.someOtherAction}" />
    </p:dialog>
 </h:form>
```

If i press commandButton A the validation of required value inside dialog B dont let me submit values from dialog A.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and the logical solution is to split dialogs into separate forms. Moreover, the best practice is to put the form *inside* the dialog, and not vice versa.

Another solution is to explicitly tell JSF/PrimeFaces what to update and to process during an ajax request by specifying the corresponding attribute of your command button, or nesting an ajax tag inside the button.

Comment: Also, it would be good to explain that nesting `<form>` HTML components doesn't work (since that's the core of the question).

Comment: @Omar no, that just skips validation. The best option is to split the big form in two (or more) forms.